# Clear Application's Data Programmatically, Ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am working on an Ionic2 app. This app fetches a .json file from S3. I updated the .json file on S3. But when I restarted the app, it fetches the same old file.

Is there any way I can ensure that my ionic1 app always fetches the latest file.

OR. Is it possible to clear the application data in android programatically. like there is `ActivityManager.clearApplicationUserData().` in android java.

Thanks

Comment: First, is your app built with Ionic 1 or Ionic 2? Second, please post the code that you fetch the json data.

Comment: Already mentioned its an Ionic2 app. Data fetching through standard angular2 http.get().

Comment: `I can ensure that my ionic1 app always...` please corect it. Can not help without code or test result. Recomend you to re-produce your problem in https://stackblitz.com/